# Book about girl who finds a dragon egg

Tags: story-identification

A girl finds a dragon egg in a river. At some point in the book she ends up in a mountain trapped with her baby dragons while trying to save a rare dragon egg.

Comment: http://www.donitakpaul.com/books/dragonkeeper/index.html?

Comment: http://pern.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonsong?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/703323.Dragon_s_Milk?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/DragonSpell-Dragon-Keepers-Chronicles-Book/dp/1578568234?

Answer (score 4):

Long shot, but could it be...

***[DragonSpell (DragonKeeper Chronicles, #1)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578568234)*, by Donita K. Paul?**

[image: cover]

From the Amazon description:

> When Kale, a slave girl, finds a dragon egg, she is given the unexpected opportunity to become a servant to Paladin. But on her way to The Hall, where she was to be trained, Kale runs into danger. Rescued by a small band of Paladin’s servants, Kale is turned from her destination.
>
> Feeling afraid and unprepared, Kale embarks on a perilous quest to find the meech dragon egg stolen by the foul Wizard Risto. But their journey is threatened when a key member of the party is captured, leaving the remaining companions to find the Wizard Fenworth, attempt an impossible rescue, and recover the egg--whose true value they have not begun to suspect.

It came up in a Google search for `"dragon egg in a river"`, and seems to match.

Comment: Yes I think this is it. The heroine, Kale, finds the egg in a stream. She is subsequently kidnapped and taken underground by ogres.